# Microsoft Graph API error ResourceNotFound from the app, but it works from Graph Explorer, on same PC

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API.
I am using my home standalone Windows 10 PC, it is not part of any AD or any domain.
I am using Microsoft Personal Account and my personal email such as john_smith@hotmail.com
I have registered my application on Azure AD, added a secret and Mail permissions.

I am using Microsoft Graph Explorer, via Edge Browser, to read my (hotmail) email which works fine:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```

When I use a set of CURL commands and I use Microsoft Device Flow to run this:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

It works fine too.
The access token is therefore correct, because I get correct data returned from my command shell application.

However if I try to read my (@hotmail) personal email such as this command:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages`

then I get error:

ResourceNotFound Resource could not be discovered

If I use beta version like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```

I get different error:

```
MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI 
The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."
```

I have granted the following delegated permissions to my app on Azure:

"token_type":"Bearer",
scope:
email IMAP.AccessAsUser.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadBasic.Shared Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared openid POP.AccessAsUser.All profile SMTP.Send User.Read

In any case I do not receive any permission-denied errors and my Graph queries all work directly from Graph Explorer from the same PC, reading the same personal email (hotmail.com).

I am now suspecting that perhaps Device_Flow authorization will not allow me to read/write my personal Hotmail email and that Graph Explorer simply uses a different authorization method (which one?).

Answer (score 0):

I trust you are using [this graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which will get the messages in the signed-in user's mailbox. And the test you did in Graph Explorer is just a test and you may check if the result emails you get from Graph Explorer existed in your hotmail account inbox.

Coming back to the issue, I don't think Microsoft Graph API can collect messages inside hotmail account, that's because we require to set tenant id when generating an access token for calling Graph API, that means the token should only work for the specific tenant. And when you sign in Azure portal with your personal account, the real account you are using now should be similar to `johnsmith_hotmail.com#EXT#@johnsmithhotmail.onmicrosoft.com`. You can check the account by going to Azure AD -> Users -> choose your account and see details in overview blade. This means the account belongs to `johnsmithhotmail.onmicrosoft.com` tenant so it's obvious unable to get messages in hotmail account.

By the way, let's assume Graph API can get messages from hotmail, then it should be able to get messages from other kinds of email accounts, but the response properties of this API are the same. I don't think the properties from different mail servers are the same.

Basically, this API can query emails for the email address ending with `johnsmithhotmail.onmicrosoft.com`, and the email feature for these accounts should be enabled separately, for example buying a M365 E3 license and assign to that account.

Comment: Thank you. The Graph Explorer *is* reading my hotmail correctly, as well as my personal contacts, etc, from my hotmail account. This makes me think what I am trying to do is possible from Graph API on personal account. The Azure tenant name is indeed in the format you have described in your reply. Such as this: (John Smit is just sample name) john_smith_hotmail.com#EXT#@johnsmithhotmail.onmicrosoft.com. I must be doing something wrong given Graph Explorer from Edge can read my contacts correctly (personal) and can read my hotmail messages correctly, I have checked this to be true.